# How to concatenate with os.system in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, os.system

I want to properly concatenate my variable in os.system command, here is my code

```
import os

npasswd = "GeeksforGeeks"
user = 'hasnain'
groups = 'devops,developers'

os.system('useradd -s /bin/bash -G '+groups+' -m -p "$(openssl passwd -1 '"+npasswd+"')" '+user)
```

The above code successfully creates user in the system but the password is not working, and if I do the following then the password working fine

```
import os

npasswd = "GeeksforGeeks"
user = 'hasnain'
groups = 'devops,developers'

os.system('useradd -s /bin/bash -G '+groups+' -m -p "$(openssl passwd -1 GeeksforGeeks)" '+user)
```

So how can I concatenate my password variable in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

npasswd = "GeeksforGeeks"
user = 'hasnain'
groups = 'devops,developers'
str1 = 'useradd -s /bin/bash -G {} -m -p "$(openssl passwd -1 {})" '.format(groups,user)
os.system(str1))
```

Double check the spacing in str1, as that could be a bit of a problem....in general it is best to use .format() when manipulating strings in python

Comment: Ok it worked but with some changes `str1 = 'useradd -s /bin/bash -G {} -m -p "$(openssl passwd -1 {})" {}'.format(groups,npasswd,user)
os.system(str1)`